# R Filter Not Working as Expected

Tags: r

Novice R question: why is my boolean vector not filtering as expected below? I don't know why it's only filtering the first element and not the 3rd and 5th also.

```
> nums = seq(1,6); nums
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> filter = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
> nums[filter]
[1] 1 3 5      #<<==WORKS AS EXPECTED
> nums[-filter]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6  #<<==NOT EXPECTED, EXPECTING 2 4 6
```

BTW, I have tried this and it works but I thought you could omit items from a vector subset with the negative sign...

```
> nums[!filter]
[1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: `nums[-which(filter)]` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `-filter` returns `-1,0,-1,0,-1,0`, I assume R is returning `nums[-1]` and ignoring the rest of the `-filter` vector.  Obviously `!filter` is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `!TRUE = FALSE` where as `-TRUE = -1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a worked example illustrating what @Glen has already said when `-` or `!` is used in front of filter.

```r
filter = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)

-filter
#> [1] -1  0 -1  0 -1  0

!filter
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Hence, passing -filter means the first column is dropped from `nums`